# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple when print from an array

Tags: python

I am designing a quiz and I have the questions and answers on a text file separated by a comma:
Work out the value of 3 X(3² + 4)  - 8 , 31

When I try and print the [0,1] variable I get the error code list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple. I want to print the answer only not the question?

```
MathsFile = open("MathsQuestions.txt","r")
MathsQuestions123 = []
with open("MathsQuestions.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
                MathsQuestions123.append(line)
                
              

     
print(MathsQuestions123[0,1])


MathsFile.close()
```

Comment: Do you mean `MathsQuestions123[0][1]` ?

Comment: You should show a specific example of the input file, but if it is comma separated and you want to access individual fields, then you will either need to `split` the line on `','`, or else use the `csv` module or maybe `pandas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using f.readlines(). By the looks of it, f is a tuple containing the content in the txt file. With readlines, you can go line by line:

```
MathsQuestions123 = []
with open("MathsQuestions.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        MathsQuestions123.append(line)
print(MathsQuestions123[0,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print them together in a single line, the best solution would be to use a loop. For example:

```
for e in range(len(MathsQuestions123)):  
   print(MathsQuestions123[e], end=" ")
```

This will output this if your list contains elements '1', '2', '3', '4':

```
1 2 3 4
```

In case you DON'T want to output them in 1 line, then just edit the print statement to this:

```
print(MathsQuestions123[e])
```

There You Go!